# When trying to get the current user id, it returns empty

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, firebase-authentication

When I try to get the current user id, it gives out empty, so I can’t log in to my account.

```
fun getCurrentUserID(): String {
    val currentUser = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().currentUser

    var currentUserID = ""
    if (currentUser != null){
        currentUserID = currentUser.uid
    }
    return currentUserID
}
```

Comment: So most likely your `currentUser` object is null, right? So your user is not authenticated when you call this method.